# Is there a word for a number with a fractional component?

Tags: terminology

Is there a word for a number with a fractional component?

If $1$ is whole number, $1.2$ is a…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since numbers with fractional components are rational numbers, we can call those that are not integers *non-integer rationals*.

Comment: A number with a fractional component is a rational number (can be expressed as the ratio of two integers).  True, integers are also rational.  How about "non-integral rational."  An irrational number is also "non-integral", but does not exactly have "a fractional component."

Comment: @mjw That is done.

Comment: Thank you!${}{}{}$